# How to show menu in borderless form in c#?

Tags: c#

is it possible to show menu in borderless form in c#. if yes tell me the way please.thanks

Comment: Have you tried? What did (not) happen?

Comment: this is about wpf, win-forms, something else ?

Comment: What technology do you use? Win.Forms? Wpf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Set your `Form.BorderStyle = None`

This has no effect on your Menu.

Answer (score 2):

In windows forms you will want to call the following:

FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

Although, when you do this, you will need to make your own MouseDown and MouseMove event handlers to move your form around, as well as code custom minimize and maximize functionality.  If you need help with those I can aid you as well.

Good luck!